# How does one make .Include work with a segmented query?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have a search form where the user can search for car parts and I need to filter on whether or not they provided a value for the PartNumber field:

```
var query = db.Car.Include(u => u.CarPart);

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.PartNumber))
{
   query = query.Where(u => u.CarPart.PartNumber == model.PartNumber);
}
```

But this error is given:

ICollection< CarPart> does not contain a definition for 'PartNumber' and no extension method 'PartNumber' accepting a first argument of type 'ICollection< CarPart>' could be found.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you have a class `Car`, where every `Car` has a property `PartNumber` of type `ICollection<CarPart>`. Probably a one-to-many or a many-to-many relationship.
I'm not sure, but I think that every `CarPart` has a property `PartNumber`.

If you had written your type declarations instead of using var and used proper identifiers for your variables, you would have seen something like:

```
IQueryable<Car> cars= db.Cars.Include(car => car.CarParts);
if (...)
{
    cars = cars.Where(car => car.CarParts...
}
```

Now what kind of thing is CarParts? It is an `ICollection<CarPart>`. Surely you wouldn't expect that a collection would have a property PartNumber?

I'm not sure which cars you want if model.PartNumber has a non-empty value.

**I want the cars that have at least one part that has this PartNumber**

```
cars = cars.Where(car => car.CarParts
    .Where(carPart => carPart.PartNumber == model.PartNumber
    .Any()
```

In words: give me all `Cars`, with all their `CarParts`, that have at least one `CarPart` in its collection of `CarParts` that has a `PartNumber` equal to `model.PartNumber`